# SpringBoot + Neo4j: Get neo4j json result

Tags: java, json, spring, d3.js

I want to get the Neo4j JSON result using spring-data-neo, because I want to use it for a graphical rendering of the results (with d3.js). Is possible? Or I need to convert the results in JSON?

I thinked a worse solution: Use spring restTemplate and invoke the cyper query by REST API,but I would like to avoid ...

Thanks

Comment: You can expose REST  endpoint do get the data from Neo. If you are using springfor this, you don't need any conversion, spring will automcatically convert your objects to json

Comment: Yes... but in a different format from NEO4J Result. A simple key, value map. I need the typical structure of NEO4J Result (what you see when you click "Code" inside Neo4j Browser)